# "Let I uncover you" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

In [this song](https://youtu.be/MhfePuVSZp8?t=47s) the lyrics read "... So let's uncover me and then let I uncover you..." To me this sounds wrong but i'm not a native speaker and the same phrase is repeated multiple times and the word "I" could have easily be replaced with "me" since both are just one syllable.

So I wanted to ask: can "...let I uncover you..." be grammatically acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is grammatically wrong and not even colloquial.  But in song lyrics, grammar goes out the window.  Correct is “Let me uncover you.” Because the subject is the implied *you* and object of the verb *let* is *me*.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no.  It should be “me”.  However, in the context of this song, using I avoids the repetition of the word “me”.  It should be followed by an objective pronoun, rather than a subjective pronoun.  Another song that violates this rule is “You and I” by One Direction, which is grammatically wrong.

Comment: “You and I” isn’t always wrong. What was the context in the One Direction song?

Comment: A better example is *Hungry Eyes* which has the grammatically incorrect line “I feel the magic between you and I.”